# Issue with Deep-Linking to Specific Code Blocks in GitHub README Files

Tags: github, markdown

**Description:**

I'm experiencing a problem with deep-linking to specific code blocks within the README files of my GitHub repository. The links I create to highlight certain functions with line numbers redirect to a `not found page`. This issue appears to be limited to the GitHub website using desktop browsers, as the links work perfectly on the GitHub Android application.

**GitHub Bug Link:**

I have already filed a bug report on the GitHub community, but haven't received any responses yet.

- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/61830?sort=new

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Go to the README file in this repo. https://github.com/zedoh/DS-Algo/tree/main :

- Attempt to deep-link to a specific function with line numbers using the following Markdown syntax:

`[Name of the specific function](/path/to/file#Lstart-line-Lend-line)`

- Replace path/to/file with the relative path to the file containing the code.
- Replace start-line and end-line with the line numbers defining the specific code block.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect that clicking on the deep link would navigate to the corresponding code block within the README file.

**Actual Behavior:**

Instead, the link redirects to a not found page, indicating that the content is not accessible. This issue occurs exclusively on the GitHub Android app.

**Additional Information:**

- Link to the repo : https://github.com/zedoh/DS-Algo/tree/main
- One of the affected folders : https://github.com/zedoh/DS-Algo/tree/main/DS/Queue

I would greatly appreciate any help or insights from the Stack Overflow community in resolving this deep-linking issue. Thank you.

I have done so much changes around the md syntax, but still the issue exist.

the fact that the issue isn't existed when using Github android app, makes me kinda sure that it is a bug on desktop websites.